# Delete row using datatable plugin then delete it from database

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable

how to delete specific row from datatable using button founded in each row
and in the same time i want to delete this row from database
how to make it using jquery ?
id of delete button is (removeBtn)
delete row when i press on this button .. (remove single row by single button)
the code of table ..

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="liveSearch">

                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center">#</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">col1</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">col2</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">col3</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">col4</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">col5</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">col6</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $servername = "localhost";
                        $username = "root";
                        $password = "";
                        $dbname = "msk";

                        // Create connection
                        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                        // Check connection
                        if ($conn->connect_error) {
                            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                        }

                        $per_page=5;
                        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
                            $page = $_GET["page"];
                        }
                        else {
                            $page=1;
                        }
                        $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
                        $sql = "select p.productname,p.quantity,p.onesale,p.wholesale,p.productdetailsid,s.fullname from productdetails p , supplier s where s.supplierid = p.supplierID";
                        $count = ($page*5)-4;

                        $result = $conn->query($sql);
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td name=\"ct\" id=\"ct\">" . $count++ . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row["productname"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row["quantity"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row["onesale"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row["wholesale"] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row["fullname"] . "</td>
                            <td>
                            <button class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\" name=\"removeBtn\"><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i> </button>
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" id=\"id\" value='".$row["productdetailsid"]."'>
                            </td>"
                            ;
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }
                        }
                        $conn->close();
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first write down click event on DataTable which injects some class (ex : selected ) on that row. Then you need to get the selected row in the `removeBtn` click and just call remove function on DataTable. You can post an AJAX request on button click and on success you can delete the row for better understanding. Here's sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );

    $('#removeBtn').click( function () {

     $.ajax({
       url: "sample.php", 
       success : function(data){
          //delete the row
          table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );
        },
       error: function(xhr){
           //error handling
        }}); 

    } );
} );
```

Here's a link for description:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

Comment: when i press on row the row not selected .. why ?

Comment: You need to add selected class in CSS.

Comment: Or use latest CSS file given in the demo.

Comment: when i use it , The form of table is inconsistent !!

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle or some demo so that i can edit it ?

Comment: Yes. CSS of jQuery DataTable plugin. And post a full demo.

Comment: just this about select !

Comment: put some different background color. So that you can identify easily

Comment: And you need selected class. Not selectable.

Comment: Yes. Use that link in your page. Instead of any other CSS. and it will work.

Comment: What happens ? Which browser are you using and have you checked network and console for any 404 or other errors ?

Comment: finally it is run ,, but The form of table is inconsistent !! :(

Comment: last question .. how to get row data for delete it from db ?

Comment: This is how you can fetch whole row data :`var row1 = table.row('.selected').data();` . Then select your unique/primary column value and send it through AJAX to web service and remove that column from DB based on that unique or primary key.

Comment: Here's link : https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data(). **Happy Coding**